# как установить русский язык в гимп

Tags: windows-7

Привет всем ставила гимп и забыла установить русский язык. Как установить русский язык теперь? Использую Win 7 x32. GIMP версии 2.10

Comment: я не эксперт, но погуглив нашел офф доку (https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/ru/gimp-fire-up.html#gimp-concepts-running-language). попробуйте по ней сделать

Comment: нет. Не помогло

Comment: Что именно не помогло? Вы выбрали в меню русский язык, а остался английский?

Comment: У меня вообще нет русского языка в параметрах гимпа. там стоит Default и английский

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решила всё сделать
сама. Ответ оставлю тут. Может кому-то пригодиться

1. Создаем папку locale по пути папка_с_гимпом/share
2. Скачиваем архив по ссылке
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L2gNkPihm45Qsmhub8f6UFPgltejHV-G/view?usp=sharing
3. Вытягиваем файлы из архива в папку locale которую создали ранее
4. Перезапускаем ГИМП. Если язык не установился, ставим в настройках ру язык

Comment: пересмотрел кучу гайдов которые не смогли мне помочь, но к счастью встретил ваш коментарий и всё получилось спасибочки ♥

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переустановить GIMP, в самом начале процесса загрузки вам придёт сообщение примерно такое - "Какой язык использовать в процессе установки?" или что-то в этом духе. Выберите Русский язык, и готово.
Качайте GIMP [отсюда.](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

Поправка -
Вот [как установить gimp на русском языке.](https://info-comp.ru/softprodobes/609-review-and-install-gimp-on-windows.html)

Comment: я так и делала из самого начала. Язык русский поставила, но не помогло. И гимп был скачан с офф сайта

Comment: Какой язык вы используете на компьютере?

Comment: конечно же русский

Comment: Ну.. с такой проблемой не сталкивался, было также, переустановил - нажал на "Использовать Русский Язык" - и сработало. Что касается вашей проблемы, то я не знаю.

Comment: а какие файлы ты устанавливал? Потому что я не ставила языковый пакет, и думала, что сама поставлю потом

Comment: @Виктория В смысле "какие"? Просто gimp, в самом начале установки там и спрашивают какой язык использовать

Comment: Я использовала ручную установку